# SQL Server 2008 query for inserting error

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
insert into salary(name, basic) 
values('EEE', 20000), ('FFF', 25000)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'FFF'.

`name` column is of type `varchar` and `basic` columns is of type `int`.

I am using SQL Server  2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm successfully able to create table and insert using same query which you are using.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a09da/1

```
CREATE table salary(name varchar(20),[basic] int);

insert into salary(name,[basic]) 
values('EEE',20000), 
('FFF',25000);

SELECT * from salary;
```

Read this for [Insert multiple using one query.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/)

Note : As Leslie Davies pointed out this syntax for inserting multiple records using one insert query is only works with MS SQL server 2008.

Comment: No problem here either. Only thing can think of is [name] and [basic]

Comment: thanks for your comments, sorry this not working :(, i am already try this one

Comment: @raja can you drop your salary table and try running the code I've provided in answer.

Comment: Are you sure you are running SQL Server 2008?  This multiple record insert feature was added in 08 as far as I know and the above syntax is not available in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: i am use that query already in another one table, now it's problem of that, i am using MS SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: create table salary(id int identity primary key,name varchar(25),basic int) **insert into salary(name,basic) values('BBB',12000), ('ccc',13000);**

Comment: it's working, but i am using another one host MS SQL SERVER, in this server not worked that please tell that what the problem. **server site name ***Somee.com*** **

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer thanks for you advice http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf3ea/1 it best site for working online

Comment: i am using online MS SQL Server like http://sqlfiddle.com that server name is https://somee.com/DOKA/DOLogin.aspx in that server not working the above query. what is the problem for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
insert into salary(name, basic) values('EEE', 20000);
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!